# NodeJS array.indexof is orders of magnitude faster than set.has and set.has is orders of magnitude faster than array.indexof !== -1

Tags: arrays, node.js, set

I know that time complexity kicks in for large inputs, but for any input array.indexof is faster.
E.g. for n=20.000, array takes 0.008ms, while set takes 0.4ms

I've tested array vs set using this code:

```
const NS_PER_SEC = 1e9;
const MS_PER_NS = 1e-6

function runTest(test) {
    let time = process.hrtime();
    test();
    let diff = process.hrtime(time);
    return (diff[0] * NS_PER_SEC + diff[1])  * MS_PER_NS 
}

function makeRandomString() {
    let length = Math.round(Math.random() * 4 + 2);
    let result = '';
    let characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789- ';
    let charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;//Math.floor(Math.random()); //result;
}

function main() {
    let testCases = [10, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 40000, 100000, 10000000];
    let times = 5000;
    let words = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        words.push(makeRandomString());
    }

    for (let tci = 0; tci < testCases.length; tci++) {
        let array = [];
        const items = testCases[tci];
        for (let i = 0; i < items; i++) {
            array.push(makeRandomString());
        }
        console.log('List ' + items);
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            let res = runTest( () => {
                for (let j = 0; j < times; j++) {
                    let tmp = array.indexOf(words[j]);
                }
            });
            console.log(res);
        }
        console.log('Set ' + items);
        let set = new Set(array);
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            let res = runTest(() => {
                for (let j = 0; j < times; j++) {
                    let tmp = set.has(words[j]);
                }
            });
            console.log(res);
        }
    }
}
main();
```

But by only changing the following line:

```
                    let tmp = array.indexOf(words[j]);
```

into:

```
                    let tmp = array.indexOf(words[j]) !== -1;
```

I get expected results - e.g. for n=20.000, array takes 333ms, and set 0.4ms.

How can this be? Surely `!== -1` can't slowdown the line by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

I do not agree that [**Set.has**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) is *"orders of magnitude"* slower than [**Array.indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). I think there is some kind of V8 code caching mechanism triggering and that's why you see those results.

As I look at your code I see that you are running the same test with the same values for 10 times:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let res = runTest(() => {
        for (let j = 0; j < times; j++) {
            let tmp = array.indexOf(words[j]);
        }
    });
    console.log(res);
}
```

I am not sure that your tests are correctly done.
When I tweak your script to look like this:

```
const NS_PER_SEC = 1e9;
const MS_PER_NS = 1e-6

function runTest(test) {
    let time = process.hrtime();
    test();
    let diff = process.hrtime(time);
    return (diff[0] * NS_PER_SEC + diff[1]) * MS_PER_NS
}

function makeRandomString() {
    let length = Math.round(Math.random() * 4 + 2);
    let result = '';
    let characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789- ';
    let charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}

function main() {

    let testCases = [100000, 200000, 300000, 400000];
    let times = 5000;
    let testResults = {};

    for (let tci = 0; tci < testCases.length; tci++) {
        let array = [];
        let words = [];
        const items = testCases[tci];

        for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            words.push(makeRandomString());
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < items; i++) {
            array.push(makeRandomString());
        }

        let set = new Set(array);
        let msSetTest = runTest(() => {
            for (let j = 0; j < times; j++) {
                let tmp = set.has(words[j]);
            }
        });

        let msArrayIndexOfTest = runTest(() => {
            for (let j = 0; j < times; j++) {
                let tmp = array.indexOf(words[j]);
            }
        });

        let msArrayIndexOfEqTest = runTest(() => {
            for (let j = 0; j < times; j++) {
                let tmp = array.indexOf(words[j]) !== -1;
            }
        });

        testResults[`${items} items`] = { 'Set.has (ms)': msSetTest, 'Array.indexOf (ms)': msArrayIndexOfTest, 'Array.indexOf !== -1 (ms)': msArrayIndexOfEqTest };
    }

    console.table(testResults);
}

main();
```

I see the following output:

```
┌──────────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┐
│   (index)    │    Set.has (ms)    │ Array.indexOf (ms) │ Array.indexOf !== -1 (ms) │
├──────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┤
│ 100000 items │ 1.0594569999999999 │    1335.504929     │        1341.52334         │
│ 200000 items │      2.264941      │    2004.631142     │    2931.9868469999997     │
│ 300000 items │ 2.2363969999999997 │      0.851231      │        4597.312417        │
│ 400000 items │      1.05495       │ 5333.842428999999  │        5308.093365        │
└──────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘
```

Note the value for `300000 items Array.indexOf` is **0.851231 ms** the code caching probably took place and when using `!==` cache was not able to take place.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Tests are correct (as are yours), I just did them a few times to see the variance. I really doubt that code caching took place. I can't find the answer anywhere on the net, but I suspect that the array.indexOf line gets somehow optimized away by the V8 engine as its result is never used. Could that be the possible cause?

Comment: Such an optimization is possible, but once again we are speaking about possibilities not the actual cause of this behavior. If exact answer should be given we need to go and investigate the [**V8 source code**](https://github.com/v8/v8) or someone of the core team to answer this. Anyway I suggest you to use `Set.has` because in all the tests it looks very stable and giving quite good results :)